# Найти в строке символы в нужной последовательности

Tags: python

Есть ли в Python простой способ определить в строке символы в нужной последовательности?

Последовательность: `'xyz'`

Строка: 'yyz**x**xxz**y**yyx**z**yyx' (нужные выделены жирным)

Вывод: `True`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По-питонски:

```
from functools import reduce

def contains(sub, string):
  return reduce(lambda a, c: a + 1 if a < len(sub) and c == sub[a] else a, string, 0) >= len(sub)
```

Почти, что псевдокод:

```
def contains(sub, string):
  counter = 0
  for i in string:
    if counter < len(sub) and sub[counter] == i:
      counter += 1
  return counter == len(sub)
```

Наиболее эффективный вариант:

```
def contains(sub, string):
  counter = 0
  for i in string:
    if sub[counter] == i:
      counter += 1
      if counter == len(sub): return True
  return False
```

---

```
print(contains('xyz', 'axbycz'))  # True
print(contains('xyz', 'axbcz'))   # False
print(contains('aa', 'axbcz'))    # False
```

Comment: В первом варианте, питоновском, с такими данными: `contains('python', '123python456')`получается "IndexError: string index out of range"

Comment: За остальные варианты сенкс, всё работает.

Comment: И параметр 'str' лучше ли переименовать во что-то не из зарезервированных слов?

Answer (score 2):

Если образец (`p`) заметно короче чем текст (`s`), то этот вариант показывает лучшую производительность. Если их длина почти равна, то лучшее решение в другом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1289625/416121).

Три хитрости:

- цикл по образцу требует меньше итераций чем цикл по строке;
- функция `si` экономит время в цикле (оператор `.` требует времени и это заметно);
- условие выхода не проверяется отдельно в каждой итерации, вместо этого обработка исключения.

Код:

```
def match(p, s):
    i = 0
    si = s.index
    try:
        for c in p:
            i = si(c, i) + 1
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def contains(sub, stri):
    sub = iter(sub)
    sb = next(sub)
    for s in stri:
        if s == sb:
            try: sb = next(sub)
            except StopIteration: return True
    return False

print(contains('xyz', 'yyzxxxzyyyxzyyx'))  # True
print(contains('xyz', 'axbycz'))  # True
print(contains('xyz', 'axbcz'))   # False
print(contains('aa', 'axbcz'))    # False
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def contains(pattern, string):
    pattern = list(pattern[::-1])
    for char in string:
        if char == pattern[-1]:
            pattern.pop()
            if len(pattern) == 0: return True
    return False
```